# Dropzone Multiple File upload not working For Excel File

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, laravel, dropzone.js

I have facing a problem in Dropzone and Laravel 5.7. I am currently upload excel file to via dropzone. But it is not working correctly. For example If I add 10 files then In my database there is 10 entry with different file name but On file Storage folder there are not 10 files, It varies from 6,7,8 File. I am changing my php.ini file for `upload_max_filesize` and `max_file_uploads`. Here is my code snippet.
My Js Code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    Dropzone.options.dropzone =
        {
            parallelUploads: 1, // Uploads one (1) file at a time, change to whatever you like.
            autoProcessQueue: true,
            uploadMultiple: true,
            maxFiles: 100,
            maxFilesize: 3,
            autoQueue: true,
            renameFile: function (file) {
                var dt = new Date();
                var time = dt.getTime();
                return time + file.name;
            },
            addRemoveLinks: true,
            timeout: 50000,
            removedfile: function (file)
            {
                var name = file.upload.filename;
                $.ajax({
                    headers: {
                        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="_token"]').attr('content')
                    },
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: '{{ url("admin.pos.deleteexcel") }}',
                    data: {filename: name},
                    success: function (data) {
                        console.log("File has been successfully removed!!");
                    },
                    error: function (e) {
                        console.log(e);
                    }});
                var fileRef;
                return (fileRef = file.previewElement) != null ?
                        fileRef.parentNode.removeChild(file.previewElement) : void 0;
            },
            success: function (file, response)
            {
                console.log(response);
            },
            error: function (file, response)
            {
                return false;
            }
        };
</script>
```

My Form is

```
{!! Form::open(['method'=>'POST', 'action'=>'backend\ExcelController@multipleExcelStore', 'files'=>true, 'id' => 'dropzone_form', 'class'=>'dropzone needsclick dz-clickable']) !!}
        <div class="dz-message needsclick">
            <div class="search-block">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-xs-12">
                        <div class="upload_container">
                            <div class="upbtn_block_1">
                                Drag &amp; drop Files Here
                            </div><!--/upbtn_block_1 -->
                            <div class="up_text_block">Or</div>
                            <div class="upload_btn"><span>Browse File</span></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        {!! Form::close() !!}
```

And My controller code

```
public function multipleExcelStore(Request $request) {
    $input = [];
    $imageName = Carbon::now()->format('Y') . '/' . Carbon::now()->format('m') . '/' . uniqid() . '_' . time() . '.' . $request->file('file')->getClientOriginalExtension();
    $destinationPath = Config::get('constants.PO_MULTILE_ATTACHEMNT') . '/';
    Helper::uploadFile($request->file('file'), null, $destinationPath, $imageName);
    $input['attachment'] = Config::get('constants.PO_MULTILE_ATTACHEMNT') . '/' . $imageName;
    $input['process_user_id'] = Auth::guard('admin')->user()->id;
    $input['process_ip'] = $request->ip();
    $input['name'] = $request->file('file')->getClientOriginalName();
    PosExcel::create($input);
    return response()->json(['success' => $imageName]);
}
```

I google it but return without any success.
Thank You

Answer (score 0):

Have you tryed to remove

```
autoProcessQueue: true,
            uploadMultiple: true,
```

I have another project with multiple upload and dont need to use that argument in the javascript, Queue is possible that is the problem too, try it and tell us :)

good luck

Comment: You tell that dont upload all, but upload more of 1 file, its possible that the problem is the filesize? maxFilesize: 3, ??

Comment: I change that too but not working, Also I told in my question that My database insertion working fine but my Storage folder where the file has been not upload concurrently

Comment: If you say that in the database its registered ok, the problem as you say is storing it. try to store it with  $image->move(public_path().$path, $name); or where you want instead of use the Helper::uploadfile

Comment: But If there is problem in my Storing then why it stored some file?

Comment: its possible that the filetype, operating system... i would try to know if always are the same files that dont upload

Comment: i store with this
                $image = $request->file('file');
                $name=$image->getClientOriginalName();
                $path = '/images/users/'.$user->id.'/';
                $image->move(public_path().$path, $name);  
                and works to me ok

Comment: @JahidMahmud have you try with run command `php artisan queue:listen`?

Comment: @JinalSomaiya Yes, I tried `php artisan queue:listen` but without success

Comment: @PabloRuizSanMiguel No it is not the same file type always

Comment: if you try upload twice times same files and dont upload all, always uploaded ok same files or upload ok random files?? Tryed to store without that helper ??? https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/filesystem#storing-files